# XML syntax error?

Tags: xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <definition assembly="Service" version="1.0">
        <structure name="Request">
            <member name="notificationEvent" target="NotificationEvent"/>
         </structure>
    </definition>
```

I get an exception saying "The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed."

Doesnt say which line and doesnt give out any more information. Any ideas whats happening?

Comment: Using company's internal software. But this appears like an XML error rather than an internal tool error.

Comment: @Arjun `xmllint` validates this as acceptable XML. Are you sure it's not your internal tool?

Answer (score 1):

I validated the XML, and there is no syntax error.

I suspect that it's the parser that doesn't handle self closing tags. You could try to circumvent this flaw by using a closing tag:

```
<member name="notificationEvent" target="NotificationEvent"></member>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it the extra space before the `<?xml` at the beginning of the file?

Comment: Theres no space there. The space got inserted while copying.

Comment: Check again! The error message is consistent with white space before the prolog.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a home-grown parser then there has to be a strong suspicion that it's a bug in the parser; you can determine this easily by testing whether the XML is accepted by a mainstream parser such as Apache Xerces.

If it's not a bug in the parser, then it's almost certainly whitespace before the XML declaration.

Answer (score 0):

"The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed."

That sounds like it's the parser/validator you're using that treats `xml` as a "processing instruction" (whatever that is in your tool...)

I think it's the first line that is causing the problem. Even though it should be there according to XML standard, try once without it.

```
<definition assembly="Service" version="1.0">
    <structure name="Request">
       <member name="notificationEvent" target="NotificationEvent"/>
    </structure>
</definition>
```

**Please note that if this actually works there is a problem with the tool**

Have you checked any other XML file with this tool that actually works?